# How to style hover for parent css from child css using scss?

Tags: css, sass

I want to write hover CSS to child elemeent but when parent element hover. So something like this:

Output I want in CSS:

```
.parent {
    background:#f8f8f8;
}

.parent .child {
    color:#000;
}

.parent:hover child {
    backgruond:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

What I'm using in SCSS:

```
.parent {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    .child {
        color:#000;
        //now I want to write css here for parent:hover. how can I do this?
    }
}
```

Comment: SCSS or Less? Why have you tagged both?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you are trying to so but I think it's this

**SASS**

```
.parent {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    .child {
        color:#000;
        //now I want to write css here for parent:hover. how can I do this?
    }

    &:hover {
      background:blue;
      .child {
        color:green;
      }
    }

}
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.parent .child {
  color: #000;
}
.parent:hover {
  background: blue;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  color: green;
}
```

Use [**SASSMeister.com**](http://sassmeister.com/) for a testing tool

Comment: all I want to know if there's any solution to write css for parent:hover stage from the child css. your example given is what I've been doing so far. but everytime I have to close the child css and put &:hover to apply parent hover and so on. so I feel like there must be way. Anyway thanks for your reply